# Matlab matrix - edit

Tags: matlab

How can I edit a Matlab matrix stored as .mat in an excel-like user interface? I would like to find all instances of a particular value in a particular column and then eyeball it and edit it that way. Is there any nice way of editing matrices other than doing things like

```
matrix[4;3] = 4
```

The edited changes should be saved to the matrix for later use in matlab.

Comment: Did you check out the MATLAB's variable editor? Also, you might want to have a look at http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-BJPDGQ/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-BJPDGQ

Comment: Not sure I've seen the variable editor. How do I use that? As far as editing goes, the edited changes should be saved to the matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open [MATLAB's variable editor](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2008/04/21/variable-editor/) by double clicking on the variable in the workspace or using  `openvar x` (where x if the name of the variable you are interested in):

[image]

Alternatively it is possible to import a MAT file into an excel sheet directly by using one of the [workarounds](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-BJPDGQ/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-BJPDGQ), but it's a bit tricky.

Comment: the openvar command worked, however double clicking did nothing

Comment: Did you do the double-click on the variable in the workspace?

Comment: Well that's weird. It should work. How about selecting the variable then pressing enter?